# Limit involving a Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

> **Problem:**
>
> Consider the differential equation $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} + 10y = f(x) , \
> > x>0,$$ where $f(x)$ is a continuous function such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$.
>
> Find the value of $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} y(x)$.

**My attempt:**

Since this is a Linear Differential Equation, we can solve for $y(x)$ to get,

$$ y(x) = \dfrac{C + \int e^{10x} f(x)}{e^{10x}} $$

which gives,

$$ \require{cancel} \lim_{x \to \infty} y(x) = \cancelto{0}{\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{C}{e^{10x}}} + \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{{\int e^{10x} f(x)}}{e^{10x}} =  \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{{\int e^{10x} f(x)}}{e^{10x}} $$

But I don't know how to solve for the last limit involving the integral.

Comment: This is a famous result. If for some $k>0$ we have $f'+kf\to l$ then $f'\to 0$ and $f\to l/k$ as $x\to\infty $. Just write $f=e^{kx} f/e^{kx} $ and use L'Hospital's Rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y(x)=\frac{ \int _1^xe^{10 t} f(t)\,dt}{e^{10x}}+C e^{-10 x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ \int _1^xe^{10 t} f(t)\,dt}{e^{10x}}\to\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$
use L'Hopital rule.
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int _1^xe^{10 t} f(t)\,dt=e^{10x}f(x)$$
so we have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{10 x} f(x)}{10e^{10x}}=\frac{1}{10}$$

Comment: Can we use l'Hopital rule near infinity.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Yes, we can. First line of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form

Comment: There is no need to solve for $y$. See my comment to question.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$y=(C+\int_1^xe^{10t}f(t)dt)e^{-10x}$$

with $ f(t)=1+\epsilon(t)$

Comment: @Aryadeva from 0 to 1, is included in the constant C.

Comment: Ok I see thanks Abdallah.